# Sitecore WebApi custom route not working controller not found

Tags: sitecore-api, webapi, routing, custom-route

Controller:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISitecoreContext _sitecoreContext;

    public ExampleController ()
    {
        
    }     

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    // GET: Manifest
    public JsonResult Test()
    {
        return Json("test");         
    }
}
```

Register Route Pipeline:

```
public class RegisterTestApiRoute
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "testApi",
            "api/testing/{controller}/{action}"
        );
    }
}
```

Patching route in config:

```
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor type="TestProject.Pipelines.RegisterTestApiRoute, TestProject" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
  </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

With all above in place the following default Sitecore webapi route works fine:

```
http://localsitecore/api/sitecore/example/test
```

but my custom route

```
http://localsitecore/api/testing/example/test
```

returns below error:

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localsitecore/api/testing/example/test'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'example'."}

I'm not sure why controller is not found, in a properly compiled code, I've tried below:

- Restarted IIS
- killed worker processes
- cleared Visual Studio temp files

No luck..

even browsed my project dll with reflector, the controller exists..

Am I missing anything here...?

Comment: Can you change MapHttpRoute to MapRoute? We are using this without any problem

Comment: Second problem is that you are using Sitecore webapi path /api/testing. We are usually using clientapi/.... instead of api/ not to clash with Sitecore OOTB controllers. try also to change /api/ to something else e.g. /nareshapi/ for now :)

Comment: Also check in Showconfig.aspx whether your RegisterTestApiRoute processor type is present in configuration

Comment: changing MapHttpRoute to MapRoute, worked... Looks like MapHttpRoute is meant for ApiController type and MapRoute for Controller type... Thank You,  @Peter Prochazka.

Comment: please add this as answer for me to accept... :)

Comment: Exactly Naresh. That is the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route pipeline definition should be changed to this one:

```
public class RegisterTestApiRoute
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "testApi",
            "api/testing/{controller}/{action}"
        );
    }
}
```

as MapRoute is meant for "normal" ASP.NET MVC controllers whereas MapHttpRoute is meant for Web API controllers.

More details about this topic can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042853/difference-between-maphttproute-and-maproute